# How to suggest a template for issues in my repo?

Tags: github, github-issues

I was wondering if there is a way to suggest a template to users that submit issues to my GitHub repository. Basically, whenever one of them opened the *Issues* form, I'd like for something like this to show up:

```
### What I want

-
-

### What I need it for

-
-

### When I need it 

-
```

So I wouldn't need to browse through poorly detailed, or excessively verbose issues when I need to set priorities.

It doesn't have to be on GitHub per se, I'm ok with a third-party client (even a paid one).

Comment: I haven't tried them but you might be able to do something with the facilities described at https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/. Issues seem to be among the events that can be triggers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply create `{user}/{repository}/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md` with any content you would like to see. It will be pasted automatically into newly created issues. You could also put it openly in the root directory of the repository, use lowercase, use a different supported file extension (like `.txt`) or omit it altogether.

- Github Help: [Creating an issue template for your repository](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-issue-template-for-your-repository/)
- Hub code: [`github/template.go`](https://github.com/github/hub/blob/master/github/template.go)